# 1 posts/communities/tags in the iOS app

Tags: bug, profile-page, ios-app, plurals

This [user](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/236447/user236447) has only 1 postS and joined only 1 communitieS:

> [image: user]

All 1 tagS from another [user profile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/206829/abvgd):

> [image: tags]

- App Version: 1.6.4
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)